# ¿Como ordenar una columna de datos?

Tags: python

Tengo un dataframe con unos datos que estan en ordenados segun como se ingresaron en los datos, al intentar ordenarlos para que queden de menor a mayor con la funcion `df.sort_values(['threadNames'])` estos quedan ordenados de esta manera:

|  | threadName | Success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4682 | Grupo de Hilos 1-1 | False |
| 162 | Grupo de Hilos 1-10 | True |
| 2817 | Grupo de Hilos 1-100 | False |
| 2899 | Grupo de Hilos 1-1000 | False |

Como hago para que quede de forma ordenada de 1,2,3... etc

Comment: Las cadenas se ordenan alfabéticamente. Si querés que se ordenen según una parte numérica, deberás extraerla y convertirla a entero.

Comment: segui tu concejo y volvi todo un entero, pero al intentar de nuevo con sort_values() me sigue regresando el mismo orden, 1, 10, 100. que puedo hacer ahi?

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, parece que la columna esta bien ordenada. Lo que queres es que los indices del dataframe no pierdan su orden?

Comment: lo que necesito es que esten ordenados de forma comun, 1, 2, 3,... y no encuentro nada de como ordenarlos de la forma que necesito

Comment: Podrias agregar un ejemplo ordenado como esperas asi te puedo entender por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Estás utilizando el método correcto, [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), pero te hace falta utilizar el argumento `key` que sirve para pasar una función al método.

Lo que vamos a hacer es:

1. Obtener el número después del guion de cada fila
2. Utilizar ese número como "identificador" o "clave" para cada "celda" de la columna
3. Ordenar utilizando el número "identificador" de cada celda

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` como ejemplo (En el archivo "sample2.csv"):

```
    threadName              Success
0   Grupo de Hilos 1-1      False
1   Grupo de Hilos 1-10     True
2   Grupo de Hilos 1-100    False
3   Grupo de Hilos 1-1000   False
4   Grupo de Hilos 1-5      False
5   Grupo de Hilos 1-7      False
6   Grupo de Hilos 1-6      False
7   Grupo de Hilos 1-4      False
8   Grupo de Hilos 1-2      False
9   Grupo de Hilos 1-9      False
10  Grupo de Hilos 1-3      False
11  Grupo de Hilos 1-8      False
```

**Nota:** Agregué filas con datos ficticios para mostrar como funciona.

## Obtener el número "identificador".

Vamos a utilizar un `regex` (Del inglés Regular Expression) para obtener el número después del guion utilizando el método [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) de la siguiente forma (Utilizando como ejemplo la primera fila del `dataframe` únicamente para ver lo que hace esta función):

```
re.split('(\d+)',df['threadName'][0])
```

Esto devuelve (Te recomiendo leer la documentación para entender como es que se forma el resultado):

```
['Grupo de Hilos ', '1', '-', '1', '']
```

Por lo que el índice que buscamos es el penúltimo, es decir `[-2]`.

## Utilizar el número como "identificador" para cada celda de la columna.

Vamos a utilizar [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) para substituir o enmascarar el contenido de la celda con el número identificador:

```
df['threadName'].map(lambda x: int(re.split('(\d+)',x)[-2]))
```

Al imprimir la línea anterior obtenemos la serie siguiente:

```
0        1
1       10
2      100
3     1000
4        5
5        7
6        6
7        4
8        2
9        9
10       3
11       8
Name: threadName, dtype: int64
```

## Ordenar utilizando el número identificador.

Por último, vamos a utilizar `sort_values` en combinación con los dos métodos anteriores para poder obtener el resultado esperado

```
df.sort_values(by=['threadName'], key=lambda col: col.map(lambda x: int(re.split('(\d+)',x)[-2])), inplace=True)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df.sort_values(by=['threadName'], key=lambda col: col.map(lambda x: int(re.split('(\d+)',x)[-2])), inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    threadName              Success
0   Grupo de Hilos 1-1      False
8   Grupo de Hilos 1-2      False
10  Grupo de Hilos 1-3      False
7   Grupo de Hilos 1-4      False
4   Grupo de Hilos 1-5      False
6   Grupo de Hilos 1-6      False
5   Grupo de Hilos 1-7      False
11  Grupo de Hilos 1-8      False
9   Grupo de Hilos 1-9      False
1   Grupo de Hilos 1-10     True
2   Grupo de Hilos 1-100    False
3   Grupo de Hilos 1-1000   False
```

**Nota adicional:* Si deseas reordenar los índices únicamente hay que utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
```

Este sería el resultado:

```
    threadName              Success
0   Grupo de Hilos 1-1      False
1   Grupo de Hilos 1-2      False
2   Grupo de Hilos 1-3      False
3   Grupo de Hilos 1-4      False
4   Grupo de Hilos 1-5      False
5   Grupo de Hilos 1-6      False
6   Grupo de Hilos 1-7      False
7   Grupo de Hilos 1-8      False
8   Grupo de Hilos 1-9      False
9   Grupo de Hilos 1-10     True
10  Grupo de Hilos 1-100    False
11  Grupo de Hilos 1-1000   False
```

## Observación

Veo un inconveniente, en caso de que tengas otros "Grupo de Hilos" es decir, que existan por ejemplo filas con valores con un `2`, `3` u otros, antes del guion, por ejemplo `Grupo de Hilos 2-9,False` el método anterior ordenaría únicamente por el valor después del guion, si necesitas ordenar por los dos números (Antes y después del guion) yo te recomendaría crear dos columnas temporales con los valores antes y después del guion, ordenar utilizando esas columnas y luego eliminarlas si no las necesitas. Para hacerlo podrías utilizar `map` como se mostró en esta respuesta.